# Excel field recognized as a phone in Safari

Tags: c#, excel, mobile-safari, epplus

I'm developing a part of application to generate an excel spreadsheet with [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/). And all works fine, but I have one problem: some data recognized as phone number by Safari on iPad (see screenshot below) and show it as link which opens popup.

[image]

I have already try to set cell number format to '@' as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30095442/2087567) but with no luck.

How can I set up this cells to show data as text, but not a phone number?

Comment: this could be done by plugin inside safari (skype)

Comment: thanks, i know this one. But I need a code solution to solve the problem on any device: with skype or not