# Using EPPlus I want to Format all cells as TEXT in a spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I want to format all cells of the spreadsheet as text before loading it with the datatable.

Here is the sample code I am using

```
StringBuilder sbitems = new StringBuilder();
sbitems.Append(@"select * from Items");
SqlDataAdapter daitems = null;
DataSet dsitems = null;

daitems = new SqlDataAdapter(sbitems.ToString(), constate);
daitems.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
dsitems = new DataSet("Items");
daitems.Fill(dsitems);

app.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Items").Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dsitems.Tables[0], true);
Excel.ExcelWorksheet worksheet2 = workBook.Worksheets["Items"];
using (var rngitems = worksheet2.Cells["A1:BH1"])//Giving colour to header
{
    rngitems.Style.Font.Bold = true;
    rngitems.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
    rngitems.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Yellow);
    rngitems.Style.Font.Size = 11;
    rngitems.AutoFitColumns();
}

worksheet2.Cells["A1:BH1"].AutoFitColumns();
worksheet2.Cells["A1:BH1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;

app.SaveAs(new System.IO.FileInfo(@"D:\ItemsData\testfileexcelnew.xlsx"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force EPPLUS to read as text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429797/force-epplus-to-read-as-text)

Answer (score 36):

Try setting Number format as @
ex: `rngitems.Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";` 
@ formats cell as Text.

Reference : [Force EPPLUS to read as text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29429797/force-epplus-to-read-as-text)
possibly duplicate of above thread.

Comment: Should be rngitems.Style.Numberformat.Format = "@"; <-- you forgot the "Style" object in your solution.

Comment: Yes, @BrianLegg i forgot `Style` before Numberformat. added it now. Thanks.